# Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"

Tags: sockets, ssl, joomla3.0

I'm trying to figure out "why" I'm getting an error message from the Joomla 3.X component Gcalendar (google calendar). The error message is below.

```
Error Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error
#-912967449: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

I have read several other threads on here and other sites but most outline 'how' to enable/install/etc... SSL. I've copied/pasted the info.php data into a [google doc here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MAwJ8htYhEbTA0zdunCBOsaLHznOxlTgsCjnylEekHo/edit?usp=sharing). Everything dealing with SSL is labeled as 'on' or 'installed.

The server is not 'public' right now, it is only available from within the school district's network. Could this be the reason for the problem?

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: obviously it's not on, otherwise you wouldn't be getting the error. Did you check `phpinfo()` output to see if ssl really is on? If not, you've been modifying the wrong php.ini file(s) and/or have forgotten to restart your webserver so the new settings take effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
ssl://www.google.com:443
```

should be

```
https://www.google.com:443
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error as well. In my case it was because I was working locally, not on the live site. Once I put it live, it worked fine. Just putting this here in case anyone else comes across the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Install OpenSSL module for php:**

```
  1. In the php.ini file, 
add this line "extension = php_openssl.dll" 

 2.Make sure that the folder "ext" have this dll, 
if not then add the desired version.
```

**Установить для php модуль OpenSSL:**

```
1)В файле php.ини,
добавь строку  "extension=php_openssl.dll"

2) Убедись что в папке "ext" есть эта dll,
если нет то добавте необходимой версии.
```